# how to use estimate-shipping-methods api

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods, rest-api

How i can use this API URL Without adding product to cart?

```
     "rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods"
```

I check on checkout and find should pass address id for collect MG shipping method.
But it is when true  we add the product to cart ... So now i wanna find how i can use above API URL without add product to cart.

Comment: try this `/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id`

Comment: oops ... it worked after add product to cart ... i want collect shipment amount before it @kunj